# Get unexpected token when execute Hibernate Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to execute this query:

```
String hql = "select e.donvi from " + BIDVTygia.class.getName() + 
    " e where e.dateUpdate = (select * from (select v.dateUpdate from " + 
    BIDVTygia.class.getName() + " v order by v.dateUpdate desc  ) where ROWNUM = 1)";
```

I get an error:

> unexpected token: (

or

> unexpected token: *

or

> unexpected token: where

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you debug this line and get the value of the variable 'hql', what is in it?. This may point to the problem

Comment: why cant you omit the **select * from** and use only single inner query and include the where condition in that inner query

Comment: A suggestion, your subquery may change to `select max(v.dateUpdate) from BIDVTygia v`, which may be executed faster.

Comment: #Alex :  sr , i fogot note that i using Oracle ! so can't using max(v.dateUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an alias in the second select, then use it to get only the returned value :

```
select
   e.donvi 
from
   BIDVTygia.class.getName() e 
where
   e.dateUpdate = 
   (
      select
         ALIAS_NAME.dateUpdate -- <---------Use the alias to get the value (don't return *)
      from 
         (
            select
               v.dateUpdate 
            from
               BIDVTygia.class.getName() v 
            order by
               v.dateUpdate desc
         )
         ALIAS_NAME -- <--------------------Use an alias
      where
         ROWNUM = 1
   )
```

Comment: Hi YCF_L !
Alias_name - what is this? tks for reply

Comment: @NguyễnTuấn you can give any name like you do with `BIDVTygia.class.getName() e`